# Add Wordpress sidebar using shortcode - conflicts with following custom meta

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, shortcode

Trying to add a sidebar by creating and using a shortcode. I can get the sidebar to show, but it then causes issues with custom meta that creates buttons at the bottom of the page, after `the_content();`. This is the code to create the shortcode `[sidebar]`:

`function sidebar_sc( $atts ) {

    ob_start();

    dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar');

    $html = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return '

    <aside id="sidebar">'.$html.'</aside>';

    }

    add_shortcode('sidebar', 'sidebar_sc');`

My page template has this:

`<?php echo the_content(); ?>

<?php if($meta_button_t_1 || $meta_button_t_2 || $meta_button_t_3) { ?>

<?php get_template_part('section', 'pageButtons'); ?>

<?php } ?>`

And the template part 'pageButtons' has this:

`<div id="page_buttons" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">

<?php if($meta_button_t_1) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $meta_button_h_1; ?>" class="cr_btn_large" title="The Revolving Stage Co: <?php echo $meta_button_t_1; ?>" id="page_button_1"><?php echo $meta_button_t_1; ?></a>

<?php } if($meta_button_t_2) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $meta_button_h_2; ?>" class="cr_btn_large" title="The Revolving Stage Co: <?php echo $meta_button_t_2; ?>" id="page_button_2"><?php echo $meta_button_t_2; ?></a>

<?php } if($meta_button_t_3) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $meta_button_h_3; ?>" class="cr_btn_large" title="The Revolving Stage Co: <?php echo $meta_button_t_3; ?>" id="page_button_3"><?php echo $meta_button_t_3; ?></a>

<?php } ?>

</div>`

Without using the `[sidebar]` shortcode, the buttons show fine. If I include the shortcode, then I get the `div` but it's empty. If I include the template part before `the_content();`, everything works except it's obviously in the wrong place.

Comment: `<?php echo the_content(); ?>` is wrong, it's either `<?php the_content(); ?>` or `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for answering, `echo the_content();` and `the_content();` are outputting the same thing for me. `echo get_the_content();` gives me the content as plain text and prints the shortcodes. No buttons though...

Comment: `the_content` prints the content so no need to echo. To execute shortcodes and other filters use `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );`

Comment: I see, it still only outputs what the first two do though. Any other ideas?